# Mirrored Cube Rooted Fraction Looks Weird

Tags: fractions, sqrt

I was testing something with Overleaf, and then a weird result was output.

[image]

What's more weird is that I went to a Discord server where a TeX-rendering engine exists. This is its result:
[image]

It's a really simple piece of code:

```
\Huge$$\sqrt[3]{\frac{100}{300}}$$
```

While This one looks better, I like how the first one appears. How can I keep the look of the first cube root, but also align the 3 properly? Also, why's this happening?

**UPDATE:** This question is related to the original one.

I defined a new command that is a mirror of the root (`\newcommand{\asqrt}[2][1]{\reflectbox{\ensuremath{{\sqrt[#1]{#2}}}}}`) in the preamble. Its size is smaller than the normal root:

[image]

Here's how I call both of them:
`\Huge\[\ \sqrt[n]{\frac{100}{300}} \quad \asqrt[n]{\frac{100}{300}}\]\`

Why are they different?

Comment: note also `$$` should not be used in latex

Comment: The `\reflectbox` will make the argument in `\textstyle` instead of `\displaystyle`.  If you add `\displaystyle` before the `\sqrt` in the definition of `\asqrt`, it should match.

Comment: That is to say, `\newcommand{\asqrt}[2][1]{\reflectbox{\ensuremath{{\displaystyle\sqrt[#1]{#2}}}}}`

Comment: It's not really considered good practice to completely change the question, including changing the title after answers are posted. Any readers may wonder why my answer doesn't mention reflection at all. But I'll extend my answer this time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Almost any document using math should load `amsmath` which provides many additional math features and corrects this

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\Huge
a
\[\sqrt[3]{\frac{100}{300}}\]
\end{document}
```

If you want the straight form use the `cmex10` option

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[cmex10]{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\Huge
a
\[\sqrt[\leftroot{6}\uproot{-6}3]{\frac{100}{300}}\]
\end{document}
```

---

With either definition, you can add a reflectbox in a mathpalette so it works in all styles

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[cmex10]{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand\asqrt[1][]{\mathpalette{\aasqrt{\sqrt[#1]}}}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\aasqrt[3]{\reflectbox{$\m@th#2#1{#3}$}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\Huge 

$\sqrt{x} \qquad \asqrt{x}$


$\sqrt[3]{x} \qquad \asqrt[3]{x}$

a
\[
\sqrt[\leftroot{6}\uproot{-6}3]{\frac{100}{300}}
\qquad
\asqrt[\leftroot{6}\uproot{-6}3]{\frac{100}{300}}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

I took the question to mean you wanted the `\surd` more vertically oriented.

What I do is vertically stretch the argument 50% before applying the square root.  The greater height makes the `\surd` orient itself more vertically.  Then I vertically compress the result back to its original scale.  Note the root degree (optional argument) needs to be stretched separately, so that the  recompression brings it back to proper scale.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel,amsmath}
\newcommand\xsqrt[2][]{%
  \vstretch{.666}{\sqrt[\vstretch{1.5}{#1}]{\vstretch{1.5}{\!#2}}}
}
\begin{document}
\Huge
\[
x\xsqrt[3]{\frac{100}{300}}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What's the `\!` part of there in the second argument?

Comment: @BoredComedy It is a small backspace.  I found the argument shifted more to the right than I wanted, for some reason.